# How to group by continuous rows in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table like:

```
id version count
1  0       3
2  0       4
3  0       3
4  1       3
5  1       2
6  1       1
7  0       3
8  0       5
```

I want to get a result like:

```
min_id version sum
1      0       10
4      1       6
7      0       8
```

If I use `SELECT MIN(id), version, sum(count) group by version`  I get this:

```
min_id version sum
1      0       18
4      1       6
```

Because `GROUP BY` combines everything in the same version. I want to combine only those versions which are continuous, based on id.

Comment: So, the numeric value of ID has a meaning? (it indicates order?)

Comment: Why does the older version number get re-used later in time? Why doesn't version always increase in value, never decrease?

Answer (score 4):

This is hard to do in SQLite, but possible.  Now, the performance is awful, but the idea is that you count the number of rows before any given row with a *different* id.  This identifies each group!  Voila!

```
select version, min(id), max(id), sum(count)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.version <> t.version and t2.id < t.id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by version, grp;
```